# TypeError: Rect argument is invalid pygame

Tags: pygame

i am new to pygame and wanted to make a game i found a playlist online at https://www.youtube.com/playlistlist=PLQVvvaa0QuDdLkP8MrOXLe_rKuf6r80KO t i followed it but i got a error like this

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/pi/firstgamepyg.py", line 78, in <module>
> game_loop()
> File "/home/pi/firstgamepyg.py", line 65, in game_loop
> things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, black)
> File "/home/pi/firstgamepyg.py", line 15, in things
>  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, color,(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh))
> TypeError: Rect argument is invalid
> ```

this is my code

```py
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()
dw = 800
dh = 600
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
cw = 96
gamedisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((dw,dh))
cimg = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/Downloads/car.jpeg')

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, color, thingh): 
    #error on next line 
    pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, color,(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh))

def car(x,y):
    gamedisplay.blit(cimg,(x,y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textsurface = font.render(text, True, red)
    return textsurface, textsurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((dw/2),(dh/2))
    gamedisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    game_loop()

def crash():
    message_display('wasted')

def game_loop():    
    x = (dw * 0.45)
    y = (dh * 0.65)
    x_change = 0
    thing_startx = random.randrange(0,800)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 7
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100
    pygame.display.set_caption('A bit Racey')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    gameexit = False

    while not gameexit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameexit = True
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change
        gamedisplay.fill(white)
        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, black)
        thing_starty += thing_speed

        car(x,y)
        if x  > dw - cw or x < 0:
            crash()
            gameexit = True

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(100)

game_loop()
pygame.quit() 
quit()
```

i was trying to  make a game where you  are a car and avoid blocks but i cant add the blocks because i get an error

Comment: `def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):` rather than `def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, color, thingh):`. Swap the last two formal parameters.

Comment: i tried it and it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

your `things` function is formatted incorrectly. you have the parameter list as `(thingx, thingy, thingw, color, thingh)` but then you call it as `(thingx, thingy, things, thingh, color)`. to make the errors go away all that you need to do is in the function definition switch `color` with `thingh`